# Hi, Does anyone knows why IVotes interface just need pass address be arguments

Tags: ethereum, solidity

The IVote here is an interface, why do I pass the address directly into it when deploy, and this address is not the address of the Vote contract
Deploy

```
const MyGovernor = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyGovernor");
const governor = await MyGovernor.deploy(futureAddress);
```

MyGovernor

```
contract MyGovernor is Governor, GovernorSettings, GovernorCountingSimple, GovernorVotes, GovernorVotesQuorumFraction {
    constructor(IVotes _token)
        Governor("MyGovernor")
        GovernorSettings(1, 1, 0)
        GovernorVotes(_token)
        GovernorVotesQuorumFraction(4)
    {}
...
}
```

IVotes

```
interface IVotes {
   // no constructor, only function and event
}
```

Figure out what happened when i use IVote interface